# Why the set of hash id generated by java is almost the same each time,but after calling System.gc() it has more variations?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I tried to collect the object id generated by java and then sort them to see the pattern:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        java.util.ArrayList<Integer> a=new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
            //String obj3=new String();
            //Object obj2=new Object();
            Object obj=new Object();
            a.add(System.identityHashCode(obj));
        }
        java.util.Collections.sort(a);
        for(Integer i:a){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

at start I think the object id should be different each time because in my impression the object id should be related to object address,but after I run the code several times it seems return the same set of object id:

```
205238968
242666487
400535505
424201356
447267976
580487944
592598094
657291792
860080307
1040108132
1165259232
1265744841
1586482837
1608535231
1914494719
2053965899
```

even have variation,the set of object id is very similar:

```
205238968
242666487
400535505
424201356
447267976
580487944
592598094
657291792
860080307
1040108132
1165259232
1586482837
1608535231
1914494719
2053965899
2127478981
```

I try to change the program by create some extra object during collecting object id:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        java.util.ArrayList<Integer> a=new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
            String obj3=new String();
            Object obj2=new Object();
            Object obj=new Object();
            a.add(System.identityHashCode(obj));
        }
        java.util.Collections.sort(a);
        for(Integer i:a){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

but still get very similar (may be the same) set of result:

```
205238968
242666487
400535505
424201356
447267976
580487944
592598094
657291792
860080307
1040108132
1165259232
1265744841
1586482837
1608535231
1914494719
2053965899
```

but when I try to call System.gc() before each object is created:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        java.util.ArrayList<Integer> a=new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
            System.gc();
            Object obj=new Object();
            a.add(System.identityHashCode(obj));
        }
        java.util.Collections.sort(a);
        for(Integer i:a){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

the set of object id has more variations each time(but still found some value same as before):

```
242666487
355475160
550670442
582642819
644278293
657291792
764062238
781143987
1165259232
1220081709
1579321858
1697022030
1726858146
1819177159
2065554654
2094048729
```

why do it happen?

Comment: Possibly switched to a different memory pool. Depending on what memory management system it is using, see for instance http://www.journaldev.com/2856/java-jvm-memory-model-and-garbage-collection-monitoring-tuning or google Java memory model

Answer (score 1):

There is no surprise in getting the same result from running the same program many times. Object allocation is largely deterministic and with the same JVM configuration you should expect very similar identity hash codes across runs.

Each time you perform GC, the Eden space is collected and live objects transferred to one of the Survivor spaces (each GC cycle uses the other Survivor space, the one which was inactive the last time). Objects which remain live after a few GC cycles get tenured (transferred to the Old Generation). Given the frequency of GC cycles in your code, that happens quite soon.  All of this introduces much more complexity into the arrangement of your objects, so again more variance is a quite expected outcome (although I would still expect far from random behavior).